# Cannot access data from nested Laravel collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to access nested collection attributes with the following structure `["role"=>"user_id"]` from `$space_roles` variable which contains:

```
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3168
     all: [
       App\UserGroup {#3153
         role: "CONTRIBUTORS",
         updated_at: "2019-04-25 09:03:24",
         name: "Contributeurs",
         created_at: "2019-04-25 09:03:24",
         slug: "contributeurs-2",
         id: 765,
         users: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3152
           all: [],
         },
       },
       App\UserGroup {#3156
         role: "AUTHORS",
         updated_at: "2019-04-25 09:03:24",
         name: "Auteurs",
         created_at: "2019-04-25 09:03:24",
         slug: "auteurs-2",
         id: 1554,
         users: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3169
           all: [
             App\User {#3180
               updated_at: "2019-04-25 09:01:42",
               created_at: "2019-04-25 09:01:42",
               last_name: "Lisangola",
               company: "Kinshasa Digital",
               first_name: "Christian",
               slug: "christian-lisangola",
               email: "christian@kinshasadigital.com",
               id: 1296,
             },
           ],
         },
       },
       App\UserGroup {#3159
         role: "ANIMATORS",
         updated_at: "2019-04-25 09:03:24",
         name: "Animateurs",
         created_at: "2019-04-25 09:03:24",
         slug: "animateurs-2",
         id: 1534,
         users: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3171
           all: [],
         },
       },
       App\UserGroup {#3162
         role: "ADMINISTRATORS",
         updated_at: "2019-04-25 09:03:24",
         name: "Administrateurs",
         created_at: "2019-04-25 09:03:24",
         slug: "administrateurs-1",
         id: 1323,
         users: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3172
           all: [
             App\User {#3185
               updated_at: "2019-04-25 09:03:05",
               created_at: "2019-04-25 09:03:05",
               last_name: "Calvin",
               company: "Gravity",
               first_name: "Jean",
               slug: "jean-calvin",
               email: "jean@gmail.com",
               id: 1533,
             },
           ],
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

To try get what I want, I've used the laravel collections method `pluck` by doing `$space_roles->pluck('users.id','role')` and it returns `null` for user's attributes.

But I cannot get the expected result.I've tried to do as expained here : [Accessing data from a Collection](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/pluck-from-a-nested-collection?page=1) by chaining like this `$space_roles->pluck('users')->flatten()->pluck('id')`,it works but I only access `users` and not the `role`.

I'm stuck on this.

Comment: Will there ever be more than one user per role? If so, would you want the structure to be `['role' => ['user_ids']]`?

Comment: Yes,a user can have multiple roles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `map()` collection method to return data how you would like:

```
$space_roles = $space_roles->map(function($role, $key) { 
    return [$role->role => $role->users->pluck('id')->all()];
})->values()->all();
```

`pluck()` is used to return all `id`s from the users.

Comment: Your solution seems working(i'm creating many users to make tests),but i've just a little question that i didn't menstion in the question above,instead of returning just `['roles'=>[users]]`.If i have a UserResource,how can i return it pass it instaed of `user_id`?

Comment: @ChristianLisangola better to ask in a separate question. But let me know once its up.

Comment: can you help me in this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56063136/update-dynamically-validation-rules-by-adding-new-data-in-the-controller  situation?